# What does [143x40] mean in the output of tmux list-sessions?

Tags: terminal, tmux

I have 4 tmux sessions present. When I use

```
tmux list-sessions
```

It shows the sessions with some numbers in the brackets. That is:

```
t128_1: 1 windows (created Thu Jul 19 12:20:44 2018) [71x38]
t128_2: 1 windows (created Thu Jul 19 12:20:54 2018) [71x38]
t3: 1 windows (created Thu Jul 19 12:19:59 2018) [143x40]
t6: 1 windows (created Thu Jul 19 12:20:27 2018) [71x38]
```

What does the number [AxB] mean? And why `t3` session has a different value than the others? Thanks for any explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the size of the terminal (143 columns, 40 rows) the last time a client attached to the session.